# Parse returning empty array in Swift when array has data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I am trying to get an array from a Parse.com database in my Swift app. For some reason, the array returned is always nil. I checked the permissions to make sure that the data can be accessed by my app, I find it really hard to find a starting point for this bug.

Here's my code:

```
    let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
    print("username: \(username)")
    let bannedUsers = PFUser.currentUser()!["bannedUsers"] as? NSArray
    print("bannedUsers: \(bannedUsers)")
```

The log output:

```
    username: Optional("Nmmtb07PoR")
    bannedUsers: nil
```

A screenshot from the database to show the array is not nil:
[image]

The exact value of the array:

```
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"mG33sM3fcC"}]
```

I tried playing around with the contents of the array, but no matter what I put in it, whether it's a pointer or just a string, I always get 'nil'. I hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

I added the line

```
PFUser.currentUser()?.fetch()
```

This refreshed the user and I got the proper data instead of 'nil'. Hope it helps if you have a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
let bannedUsers = PFUser.currentUser()!.bannedUsers as? NSArray
```

Comment: I get "Value of type 'PFUser' has no member 'bannedUsers'" compiler error

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("bannedUsers")`

or `PFUser.currentUser()!.valueForKey("bannedUsers")`

Your column could be not included in the currentUser object so you would have to query users and include the bannedUsers column. 
You can do it by the following:

```
let query = PFUser.query()
query?.includeKey("bannedUsers")
do {
 let user = try query?.getObjectWithId((PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!)
 let bannedUsers = user?.valueForKey("bannedUsers")
 print(bannedUsers)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: It returns 'nil' in both cases

Comment: Ok, this means the pointer is not included in your current user, could you try this PFUser.currentUser()!.valueForKey("bannedUsers").fetch()

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I added some extra columns - a new array column and a string column, in both cases I also get a 'nil'. It seems to me that for some reason I can't access user values at all

Comment: I've solved the problem - your idea with fetch() was right, it's just that I had to do fetch() on the user, not the value. The changed answer might be good, but it won't do in my case - I am using the data as a part of another query but don't want to join two queries. Still, thanks for help, I wouldn't have done it without the fetch() idea.